# Google indexing Wordpress in subdirectory disallowed in robots.txt

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, noindex, disallow

I have a headless wordpress site just using wordpress API.

My site is in the root at example.com, and wordpress live subdirectory example.com/wordpress.

I set up robots.txt as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wordpress/
Disallow: /wordpress/wp-admin/
Disallow: /wordpress/wp-login.php
```

However, looks like google still indexed pages under `/wordpress`, and I have a coverage issue warning in google search console `Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt`.

1. Most of the pages it indexed actually don't even exist, they 404. So
   I could allow google to try to crawl them and consequently de-index.
   But wow did Google even find these pages? I don't have them linked
   anywhere on my site or in my submitted sitemap.xml. E.g. something like `https://example.com/wordpress/product/awesome-product` is indexed with `No information is available for this page.`, while the real page is also indexed and exists at `https://example.com/product/awesome-product`
2. Other pages do actually exist - for example API endpoints that are
   consumed by my site. Should I care if these are indexed or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Disallow` in `robots.txt` doesn't prevent search engines from indexing pages, only from crawling them - this is a common SEO myth.

To answer your questions:

1. Googlebot finds pages not only through links and the sitemap, but also by reading the page's source code for URLs in JavaScript code, etc. It's quite clever.
2. I wouldn't worry too much about API endpoints being indexed.

The pages that you don't want to be indexed should serve up a `meta noindex` HTML tag, or a `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` HTTP header. Make sure to remove those pages from your `robots.txt` so that Google can crawl them and see the directive that they shouldn't be indexed.

More details here:

https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag

Comment: Google officially stated they are dropping support for unofficial rules earlier this month. https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-robots-txt-noindex/314961/

Comment: @RobT Good to note. Please also note that my answer does not reference/mention any of those.